# I want to create a medium in Dymola(modelica) that will vary its saturation properties with varying weight index

Tags: simulation, modelica, dymola

I'm trying to model a black liquor evaporator system. We already use dymola to create our process models for industrial simulations. Evaporator systems take the liquid/solid mixture from about 15% solids to about 70-75% solids. The saturation/boiling point properties vary considerably with the amount of solids. I can create a new medium and change ist T2P calcualtion for a single solids point. Dymola uses instream calculations that track weight percentage for a component stream. is there a way to include a varying weight percentage into the calculations for the medium, so it will change satruation properties as solids change?

I have tried modifying the T2P calculation for the medium for a given solid level, and it works, but I'd like to figure out how to make it continually variable as water is evaporated.

Comment: which medium models are you using as a basis? MSL.Media or something else? An example of your code would help to understand what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the built in mediums in our library as a basis for a new medium.  Our Medium calles simple water was probably created by a former employee who knew much more about modelica and Dymola than I do. I'm guessing he created the "simple water" medium using the "basic" medium that probably came with our dymola library. below is the expaned view of the medium

Comment: Test of pasting images

Comment: i attemped to paste in an image of the code I'm using for the mediums, and then maybe the messages I'm getting, but I am unable to paste an image into the comments.  Basically what I'm trying to do is add a function to the medium i'm creating that will calculate Boiling point rise for a given mass index of one component stream and use the result to alter the T2P calculation for the medium. I am able to modify the T2P calculation with a constant, but I need it to be a variable.

Comment: if you share the code, we could help you way easier. You can add images to your question. what do you mean with dymola library?